# stackexchange site in other language for specific communities networks

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to have a stackexchange site for some specific community in the local language of the country ?

For example, in my country, if I want to use the stackexchange to create some network community (social, education, etc), free and useful for the population, in the local language.

What are the possible solution ? customisation, collaboration, ... ?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: In the Area 51, new site is in english. The purpose is to do an 'Area 51' and Stackexchange entirely in the other language (the local language of the country)

Comment: No one prevents you from proposing a new site in another language. In fact, there are proposals for Stack Overflow in a great many languages including Turkish, German, Korean, Esperanto, Polish, French, and Russian, and Stack Overflow in Portuguese is already [a live site with a localized GUI](http://br.stackoverflow.com/). There is no localized version of Area51, though, and never will be, because the overhead would be just too high.

Comment: You mean like this? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese

Comment: If I understand well, the way to do is to propose a new site in a new language and .... waiting. In fact the language that I want to promote is Vietnamese, so if Vietnamese population is not enough to participate to the Area51, the site will never create. The raison that I want to create the stackexchange in Vietnamese is to give it to the no english largest population, that's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already work in progress towards localization. First site in non-English language is [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) which looks like this: (until it's out of private beta you can reach it via its [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese), just click "Visit the site now" in there)

> [image]

Two more will come very soon as well:

1. [Stack Overflow in Russian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)
2. [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)

And there are also proposals already for Turkish, German, Korean and more.

Comment: 'more languages to come soon' ... what do you mean ? If I propose Vietnamese, what is the chance that it will be do ?

Comment: @NhuPhung if you gather enough people to follow your proposal, your chances are not so bad. :)

Comment: 'enough people' means ... how many ? 100, 1000, ... ?

Comment: @NhuPhung 200 is enough, first you have to write sample questions though and the 200 people should be users on at least one Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I want Stack Exchange in Vietnamese :)